# Clickable and downloadable record in lightning data table LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

i am facing a problem with a lightning web component, more specifically wit the lightning datatable. In my table i have all the records of ContentDocument that are in my org. I implemented the sort function to sort them by created date.
Now comes the tricky part (for me at least): i want to be able to click on these record names and download the files.
Attaching images to be clearer.

my component:
[image: as you can see, my component is part of a custom app]

my code:

[image: html]

[image]

[image]

TLDR: I want to be able to click on the file name and download the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] to include your code as text. Wrap code blocks in triple backticks (```) to format them. Images of code are not accessible to community members using assistive technology like screen readers. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding link - change type for Name to "link" and provide download link, refer to documentation on how to set typeAttributes for link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either provide option to view the file preview or to download. Note that in the preciew, you will get the option to download, so use either one. below is the sample code for `ContentDocument`:

#### Note that below is the sample code and you need to do error handling etc properly.

`columns` for datatable:

```
columns: [
    { fieldName: 'Title', label: 'Title', sortable: true },
    { fieldName: 'FileType', label: 'Type', sortable: true },
    { fieldName: 'CreatedBy.Name', label: 'Created By', sortable: true },
    {
        label: 'View',
        type: 'button',
        initialWidth: 135,
        typeAttributes: { label: 'View File', name: 'view_file', title: 'Click to View Details' }
    },
    {
        label: 'Download',
        type: 'button-icon',
        initialWidth: 135,
        typeAttributes: { iconName: 'utility:download', name: 'download_file', title: 'Click to download' }
    }
]
```

Now, you have to handle the row actions:

```
handleRowAction(event) {
    var action = event.detail.action;
    var row = event.detail.row;
    switch (action.name) {
        case 'view_file':
            this.navigateToFiles(row.Id);
            break;
        case 'download_file':
            this.downloadFile(row.Id);
            break;
        default:
            this.navigateToFiles(row.Id);
            break;
    }
}

navigateToFiles(id) {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            pageName: 'filePreview'
        },
        state: {
            recordIds: id
        }
    });
}

downloadFile(id) {
    getContentVersion({ docId: id })
        .then((versionId) => window.open(`/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/${versionId}`))
        .catch((error) => console.error('ERROR => ', error));
}
```

Below is the apex code to get latest content version:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string getContentVersion(Id docId){
    return [
        SELECT Id, IsLatest, Title, ContentDocumentId 
        FROM ContentVersion 
        WHERE ContentDocumentId=:docId AND isLatest=true
        LIMIT 1
    ].Id;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it solved in part my problem; when i do preview file, everything is ok, but if i click on dowload then a popup error displays.
Do i need to import specific things in my code? like NavigationMixin (which i already have)?

Comment: Just to clarify, the download after the modal for the preview button opens, works perfectly; it's the second button of the data table (the one with download icon) that when clicked displays error

Comment: i just solved the issue.....i was missing the import statement for the getContentVersion method in the lwc.
Once again thanks @salesforce-sas your code works great